# How to make Model progress loader of facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am working on facebook login, Everthing working fine except when facebook app is not installed in device and facebook login action open with progressdialog at that time if user press back to cancel dialog,facebook login interrupt. What i want to achieve is to make model progress dialog of facebook login when facebook app is not installed on device. So that user can't press outside and facebook login process continue without interrupt.